# Storing JSON Array in Oracle table

Tags: java, json, oracle

I am processing huge JSON data from a file and each JSON object has an array like

```
field28436": [{
            "id": "C28679",
            "value": "Dutch"
        }, {
            "id": "C28963",
            "value": "English"
        }, {
            "id": "C28966",
            "value": "French"
        }, {
            "id": "C28968",
            "value": "German"
        }]
```

I need to store it into oracle database in a single column. Please suggest a datatype or way to store it in a single column. I am using JAVA to parse the JSON.
For Example if I parse this value as a key, value pair using hashmap how can I store it in a single column? Is it possible?

Comment: You can: Use `CLOB` column type and have a look at this question then https://stackoverflow.com/q/2887362/4636715

Comment: How big is you JSON ? If you are not goiing to exceed the max varchar2 size I would recommend you to not use clob.

Comment: Not sure about JSON size in real time I am going to process. 5700 records with 100 fields as of now. In real time it may go up to 100,000 records.

Comment: "I need to store it into oracle database in a single column." - And in a single row?

Comment: @JimmyB Yeah In a single row. Sorry didnt mention that.

Comment: Figured it out. Will be using TYPES.https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/objects.htm

Comment: Why don't you simply normalize your data model and generate the JSON "on-the-fly" if needed?

Comment: What is your preferred solution: to store the data as a JSON document or shred the data into an array of key-pairs?

Comment: @APC Create a nested table type and add it as a column in the actual table. Nested table will be having the values I parsed from JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `varchar2` column if you are 100% certain the length will never exceed 4000 bytes. Otherwise use a CLOB or BLOB column.

In any case, you should "enhance" that column with a CHECK constraint that validates that the value is a valid JSON, e.g.:

```
create table my_table
(
   id integer primary key, 
   data clob, 
   constraint validate_json CHECK (data IS JSON)
);
```

Oracle recommends to use a `BLOB` column instead to avoid the overhead of a multi-byte character set used by `CLOB`. However that makes handling the JSON a bit more complicated from within Java (or any SQL client).

To store such a value use a `PreparedStatement` and use the `setString()` method. Current Oracle drivers don't need `setClob()` for long strings any more - at least not for INSERT or UPDATE statements.

```
String jsonData = "field28436": [....]";
PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(
      "insert into my_table (id, data) values (?, ?)");
pstmt.setInt(1, 42);
pstmt.setString(2, jsonData);
pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

To read the data would use something similar:

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement("select data from my_table where id = ?");
pstmt.setInt(1, 42);
ResultSet rs = psmt.executeQuery();
if (rs.next()) {
  String jsonData = rs.getString(1);
}
```

For more information I recommend to read the [JSON Developer's Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/adjsn/overview-of-storage-and-management-of-JSON-data.html)

Comment: Need to  store that data in a standard datatype formats so that I can retrieve or update easily. CLOB and BLOB are last options.Looking for some special datatypes like varray etc..I am not sure about 12c features. If something new in 12c please suggest.

Comment: @user3575174: `CLOB` **is** a standard data type. You can "easily" retrieve and update the value in there (as I have shown). There is no need to treat a CLOB differently in your Java code. Do read the manual link from my answer.

Answer (score 0):

i had this situation where i had to store the json message in a column in a table. we used CLOB Datatype and it worked well

Comment: This should be a comment not a answer, bro